# Проблема с вызовом .bind vanilla js | Влияние pointer-events: none на js события

Tags: javascript, css

Есть такой код:

```js
class BeforeAfterSlider {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Start");
    this.active = false;
    this.scroller = document.querySelector(".scroller");
    this.body = document.body;
    this._scrollingRemove = this._scrollingRemove.bind(this);
    this._scrollingAdd = this._scrollingAdd.bind(this);
    this.scroller.addEventListener("mousedown", this._scrollingAdd);
    this.scroller.addEventListener("mouseup", this._scrollingRemove);
  }

  _scrollingAdd() {
    console.log("mousedown");
    this.active = true;
    console.log("change this.active => ", this.active);
    this.scroller.classList.add("scrolling");
    console.log("ADD CLASS SCROLLING => ", this.scroller.classList.contains("scrolling"))
  }

  _scrollingRemove() {
    console.log("mouseup");
    this.active = false;
    console.log("change this.active => ", this.active);
    this.scroller.classList.remove("scrolling");
    console.log("REMOVE CLASS SCROLLING => ", this.scroller.classList.contains("scrolling"))
  }
}

var obj = new BeforeAfterSlider();
```

```css
#page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

.before,
.after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content-image {
  height: 100%;
}

.after {
  width: 125px;
}

.scroller {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0.9;
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.scroller:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.scrolling {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 1;
  // z-index: 1;
}

.scroller__thumb {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.scroller:before,
.scroller:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 7px;
  height: 9999px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3.5px;
  z-index: 30;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.scroller:before {
  top: 100%;
}

.scroller:after {
  bottom: 100%;
}

.scroller {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}

.scroller:before,
.scroller:after {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="before">
      <img class="content-image" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1638/26145024230_06acd55d1b_b.jpg" draggable="false" /> </div>
    <div class="after">
      <img class="content-image" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1663/25814974803_d4c55ff708_b.jpg" draggable="false" />
    </div>
    <div class="scroller">
      <svg class="scroller__thumb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" style="fill:#fff"/><polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" style="fill:#fff"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Не пойму почему не срабатывает функции `_scrollingRemove()` при отжатии кнопки.

Убирал `this._scrollingAdd = this.scrollingAdd.bind(this);` и функция `_scrollingRemove()` вызывалась как должна, но `_scrollingAdd()` не работал, т.к. выдавало ошибку:

> cannot read propery 'classList' of undefined

В общем вопрос: что в этом коде не так и как поправить? Весь день голову ломаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После события нажатия мыши к `.scroller` добавляется класс `scrolling`, смотрим на стили:

```
.scrolling {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

`pointer-events: none;` - отключает события мыши, вместе с событием `mouseup`. Убираем эту строчку - все работает:

```js
class BeforeAfterSlider {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Start");
    this.active = false;
    this.scroller = document.querySelector(".scroller");
    this.body = document.body;
    this._scrollingRemove = this._scrollingRemove.bind(this);
    this._scrollingAdd = this._scrollingAdd.bind(this);
    this.scroller.addEventListener("mousedown", this._scrollingAdd);
    this.scroller.addEventListener("mouseup", this._scrollingRemove);
  }

  _scrollingAdd() {
    console.log("mousedown");
    this.active = true;
    console.log("change this.active => ", this.active);
    this.scroller.classList.add("scrolling");
    console.log("ADD CLASS SCROLLING => ", this.scroller.classList.contains("scrolling"))
  }

  _scrollingRemove() {
    console.log("mouseup");
    this.active = false;
    console.log("change this.active => ", this.active);
    this.scroller.classList.remove("scrolling");
    console.log("REMOVE CLASS SCROLLING => ", this.scroller.classList.contains("scrolling"))
  }
}

var obj = new BeforeAfterSlider();
```

```css
#page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

.before,
.after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content-image {
  height: 100%;
}

.after {
  width: 125px;
}

.scroller {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0.9;
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.scroller:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.scrolling {
  //pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 1;
}

.scroller__thumb {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.scroller:before,
.scroller:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 7px;
  height: 9999px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3.5px;
  z-index: 30;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.scroller:before {
  top: 100%;
}

.scroller:after {
  bottom: 100%;
}

.scroller {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}

.scroller:before,
.scroller:after {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="before">
      <img class="content-image" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1638/26145024230_06acd55d1b_b.jpg" draggable="false" /> </div>
    <div class="after">
      <img class="content-image" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1663/25814974803_d4c55ff708_b.jpg" draggable="false" />
    </div>
    <div class="scroller">
      <svg class="scroller__thumb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" style="fill:#fff"/><polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" style="fill:#fff"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```